# PowerShell Get username from System

Tags: powershell

I use a tool to login to remote PC. All my actions in remote PC will be executed by System.

My tool can executes batch and PS script.

If I run `(Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem | select username).username`
yes the output is correct.

If I run `whoami`, the output is **PC01$ nt authority\system**

If I run `$env:ComputerName`, the output is
**PC01**

If I run `$env:UserName`, the output is
**PC01$**

Can you help to explain me how does this situation can happen? Why $env:UserName does not resolve the valid user name?

Comment: PowerShell always runs in the user context of the user who started it. So, any $env will be associated with it. If are running as the system (ring 0) and trying to get the currently logged on user (ring 1),  what you are doing will not work for the reason specified. There are other ways to determine the logged-on user, via the Event logs, registry or other processes running on the target as that logged on user or using other tools on the target. The options are well documented all over the web and in Youtube videos.

Comment: See these pointers: [powershell 'get currently logged on user remote session'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell+%27get+currently+logged+on+user+remote+session%27&t=h_&ia=web)